# what is outdated diff in gitlab MR?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8

We are using gitlab version 8.4.11. sometimes we see an outdated diff in MR discussion section.

what is outdated diff and when it will occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outdated diff is where you started a discussion on some part of code, and someone pushes some code which changes that line of code where the discussion happened.

[Additional information](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36994).